# Why does the GridLayout cover the whole screen?

Tags: android, nativescript, grid-layout

I have the following HTML code:

```
<GridLayout>
  <GridLayout #background class="background">
  </GridLayout>

  <StackLayout #initialContainer class="initial-container">
    <Image src="res://logo_login">
    </Image>
    ....
    ....
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

My question is about the GridLayout with the `background` class.

This is the CSS for the class:

```
.background {
  background-image: url("res://apple");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Apparently it's the actual background (the orange background here, not the logo!).

[image]

**Question**
I don't understand why the GridLayout covers the whole screen. And even if it does, I was expecting the StackLayout to be after the GridLayout. I already know that `background-size:cover` covers the whole space, but why does the GridLayout cover the whole screen as well? And why does the logo and title display as if they are absolutely positioned when they are not in my CSS?

Comment: share your inflated rows or columns layout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer layout is a GridLayout, if you dont specify rows and columns, any layout or item inside the layout will be stacked on top of each other in the top-left-most grid cell, layered in order that they are in the html. To get around this, swap your outer layout to a StackLayout

Comment: There is no problem that I want to solve. I just want to understand how come that background takes the 100% and how come those logo+title are on top of it - without me to write it in code

Comment: Because without specifying rows and columns on your outer layout, everything within the grid layout will be stacked on top of each other, the lowest items will be on top

Comment: Thanks !. sorry ( but i'm a beginner in the field) - where is the docs that says what you've just told me ?

Comment: i dont believe there are any docs which say that, but after observations made by nativescripters (Dave Coffin's blogpost) it was found that they stack

Comment: Searched [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/meet-dave-coffin-developer-expert-for-nativescript) = but didn't find any articles.

Comment: you wont, its on the nativescript blog

Comment: BTW when you say : _layered in order that they are in the html_ - But will they be centered vert && horz && 100% fill each ? ?

Comment: that i am aware of, yes. unless the size is explicitly defined